# TypeScript - Difference between Private and Protected Variables

Tags: typescript

What is the difference between `private` and `protected` variables in TypeScript? Similar questions exist for `C#` but I am not sure if the concepts in the two languages are identical. If not, it would be useful to know the differences.

Answer (score 123):

It's the same as in other OO languages.
Private methods/members are accessible only from inside the class.
Protected methods/members are accessible from inside the class and extending class as well.

```
class A {
    private x: number;
    protected y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    getX(): number {
        return this.x;
    }

    getY(): number {
        return this.y;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    multiply(): number {
        return this.x * this.y;
    }
}
```

Notice that in class `A` there's access to both (private) `this.x` and (protected) `this.y`.
But in class `B` there's only access to `this.y` and `this.x` has this error:

> Property 'x' is private and only accessible within class A

(you can see the error in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%09private%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%09protected%20y%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.x%20%3D%20x%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.y%20%3D%20y%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09getX()%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this.x%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09getY()%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this.y%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%09multiply()%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this.x%20*%20this.y%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D))

What's important to understand though is that this is only true to typescript.
In javascript those members are accessible to anyone with a reference to the instance.

Comment: Does your last sentence mean that when transpiled to JavaScript, we lose this functionality?

Comment: @Qwerty You don't lose any functionality. What you're losing is the "private guard". That is, at runtime the private members will be exposed to anyone with a reference to an instance.

Comment: So I get all sorts of warnings in the IDE and while compiling, but the code will transpile anyway and when run, the method `multiply` will work...

Comment: @Qwerty Compilation will end with errors (not warnings), with or without an ide. If you don't have the `--noEmitOnError` flag then the compiler will still create the compiled js files. When using those, at runtime everything that was `private` or `protected` will still be completely visible, just as if it was `public`.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I only tried the example in the playground you linked, and the compiled javascript did run without any errors.

Answer (score 51):

***PRIVATE*** ***Method***:

> When a member is marked **private**, it cannot be accessed from
>   outside of its containing class.

***PROTECTED*** ***Method***:

> The **protected** modifier acts much like the **private** modifier
>   with the exception that members declared **protected** can also be
>   accessed within deriving classes.

There is **`one more`** point to add regarding **`Protected variables`**:

> when a base class variable is **protected** we cannot use its variable from **derived** class directly.

For e.g:

```
class Car{
    protected name: string;
    constructor(name: string) { this.name = name; }
}

class Mercedes extends Car{
    private noOfWheels: number;

    constructor(name: string, noOfWheels: number) {
        super(name);
        this.noOfWheels= noOfWheels;
    }

    public getIntro() {
        return `Hello, This is my ${this.name} and I have ${this.noOfWheels} wheels.`;
    }
}

let myCar= new Mercedes ("COOL Car", 4);
console.log(myCar.getIntro());  //Hello, This is my COOL Car and I have 4 wheels.
console.log(myCar.name); // Error!! , Property 'name' is protected and only accessible within class 'Car' and its subclasses.
```

> we can’t use variable **name** directly from outside of Car class, we can still use it from
>   within an instance method of Mercedes because Mercedes derives from
>   Car.

Comment: Uau! This answer should definetely be **`Protected`** !  Tx @Helping hand

Comment: Personally think that this is better answer, as the more upvoted one doesn't directly mention the difference between `protected` and "regular" property (see logging `myCar.name` in this answer).

Answer (score 12):

`protected` works in TypeScript very similarly like it does from C#. The [TypeScript release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/release-notes/typescript-1.3.html) document it as such:

> The new protected modifier in classes works like it does in familiar languages like C++, C#, and Java. A protected member of a class is visible only inside subclasses of the class in which it is declared

Whereas `private` only lets you have access to the immediate class type. Private members are not visible to subclasses.